# Java set local ip address without changing code

Tags: java, linux, sockets, libc

I have a server to which we will be adding an additional IP address. The server is a CentOS VPS running on the OpenVZ virtualization platform.

What I would like to do is introduce the new address without affecting the existing Java programs, all the existing programs should continue to use the primary address.

I realise that the Socket() constructor has a variant where one can specify the IP address used - this is not an ideal solution, because it involves changing quite a bit of code - and much of it is library code which simply doesn't expect multiple IPs, especially when performing client requests.

For the new program, I plan to explicitly specify the secondary IP in the Socket constructor, but I would like the existing programs to simply use the "default" IP without modifying them.

Is there a way to do this in my JVM configuration or OS configuration. I have administrator access to the host node too, if that helps.

**EDIT**

Here is an implementation of the accepted answer. It can be applied to most processes and is not restricted to java programs. The code is in C but one does not need to understand C to use it. Instructions are in the comments.

Explanation [here](http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html)

```
/*
Copyright (C) 2000  Daniel Ryde

This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
Lesser General Public License for more details.
*/

/*
LD_PRELOAD library to make bind and connect to use a virtual
IP address as localaddress. Specified via the enviroment
variable BIND_ADDR.

Compile on Linux with:
gcc -nostartfiles -fpic -shared bind.c -o bind.so -ldl -D_GNU_SOURCE

Example in bash to make inetd only listen to the localhost
lo interface, thus disabling remote connections and only
enable to/from localhost:

BIND_ADDR="127.0.0.1" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so /sbin/inetd

Example in bash to use your virtual IP as your outgoing
sourceaddress for ircII:

BIND_ADDR="your-virt-ip" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so ircII

Note that you have to set up your servers virtual IP first.


This program was made by Daniel Ryde
email: daniel@ryde.net
web:   http://www.ryde.net/

TODO: I would like to extend it to the accept calls too, like a
general tcp-wrapper. Also like an junkbuster for web-banners.
For libc5 you need to replace socklen_t with int.
*/



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>

int (*real_bind)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);
int (*real_connect)(int, const struct sockaddr *, socklen_t);

char *bind_addr_env;
unsigned long int bind_addr_saddr;
unsigned long int inaddr_any_saddr;
struct sockaddr_in local_sockaddr_in[] = { 0 };

void _init (void)
{
    const char *err;

    real_bind = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "bind");
    if ((err = dlerror ()) != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "dlsym (bind): %s\n", err);
    }

    real_connect = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "connect");
    if ((err = dlerror ()) != NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "dlsym (connect): %s\n", err);
    }

    inaddr_any_saddr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind_addr_env = getenv ("BIND_ADDR")) {
        bind_addr_saddr = inet_addr (bind_addr_env);
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_family = AF_INET;
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_addr.s_addr = bind_addr_saddr;
        local_sockaddr_in->sin_port = htons (0);
    }
}

int bind (int fd, const struct sockaddr *sk, socklen_t sl)
{
    static struct sockaddr_in *lsk_in;

    lsk_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)sk;
/*  printf("bind: %d %s:%d\n", fd, inet_ntoa (lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr),
        ntohs (lsk_in->sin_port));*/
        if ((lsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
        && (lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr == inaddr_any_saddr)
        && (bind_addr_env)) {
        lsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr = bind_addr_saddr;
    }
    return real_bind (fd, sk, sl);
}

int connect (int fd, const struct sockaddr *sk, socklen_t sl)
{
    static struct sockaddr_in *rsk_in;

    rsk_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)sk;
/*  printf("connect: %d %s:%d\n", fd, inet_ntoa (rsk_in->sin_addr.s_addr),
        ntohs (rsk_in->sin_port));*/
        if ((rsk_in->sin_family == AF_INET)
        && (bind_addr_env)) {
        real_bind (fd, (struct sockaddr *)local_sockaddr_in, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    }
    return real_connect (fd, sk, sl);
}
```

**Edit 2**
If the process tries to map IPv4 address to IPv6 ones eg 192.0.2.128 becomes ::ffff:192.0.2.128 then the solution does not work. To prevent java doing this use the following VM argument

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper around libc connect() which does bind() to the desired address, if not bound yet, and continues to original connect() function, and attach it to a target process using LD_PRELOAD. I was using one named "libconnect" from FreeBSD ports; regrettably, the source is gone, but restoring it (and making a Linux port) is a quite easy task (1-2 hours) for an experienced Linux programmer.

Comment: This seems to do just that http://daniel-lange.com/archives/53-Binding-applications-to-a-specific-IP.html To be clear this is a general solution for Linux and not specific to Java or OpenVZ. Some preliminary tests using the telnet client seem to indicate this is exactly what I want.